# Facebook graph API - Getting a user ID using an email address

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know in the FB graph API, when you have a user's facebook name or user ID, you can get all the functional information on that user from the graph API. When you only have the email address of a user, can you grab the fb userID from the graph API associated with that email address?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a query by email and receive the id, name, profile url etc. using the graph api. Unfortunately, that works sometimes and not others. It had been working, then this bug was reported:

Searching Facebook profile with email address is no more working with Graph API

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266?browse=search_4fa1307a895f67895398056

Then it was fixed on March 2.

Just this morning, it appears to be broken again. Using the search api, I can search by name and get results, but replacing name with email returns an empty list.

Hopefully this is an intermittent issue.

Comment: thank you Cindy, do you perhaps know any other tricks tips or some workaround for this? We want to use this in a very integral part of our signup process, but if it is this unstable, it might not be worth it...

Comment: I will mark your answer soon, just waiting to see if anyone else might know something about this....yeah I know, if it's broken it's broken, but a second opinion won't hurt...

Comment: There is an open bug report here:  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/327295460672070 if you want to follow the status of when this function will be available again.